# How to get cognito user's "username" in cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito

I created a user like:

```
  SuperAdminUser:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolUser
    Properties:
      DesiredDeliveryMediums:
        - EMAIL
      Username: !Ref SuperAdminEmail
      UserAttributes:
        - Name: email
          Value: !Ref SuperAdminEmail
      UserPoolId:
        Fn::ImportValue:
          !Sub ${BaseStack}-Cognito
```

And the user pool is defined:

```
  CognitoUserPool:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
    Properties:
      AdminCreateUserConfig:
        AllowAdminCreateUserOnly: false
        UnusedAccountValidityDays: 3
      LambdaConfig:
        PreSignUp: !GetAtt CognitoPreSignUpHook.Arn
      Policies:
        PasswordPolicy:
          MinimumLength: 8
          RequireNumbers: true
      UsernameAttributes:
        - email
```

I noticed that it fails to find the user because username looks like: `9f8aecc2-530d-411d-8d73-c3b775da1893` while `!Ref` gives the email of the user in this case. I notice this started failing when I added

```
      UsernameAttributes:
        - email
```

How can I resolve this? I noticed User resource does not allow me to get the Sub of the user ...

Comment: What is the error you're receiving? If you just create the user pool and not the user (with the UsernameAttribute you need), does it give an error or pass?

Comment: @ChrisPollard, It passes when I dont use `UsernameAttributes`. I notice the difference is: when using `UsernameAttributes` the username my code needs to use is the `Sub` (some random string) otherwise, its the email I set. I suspect thats the difference since !Ref gives the username and not the sub

Comment: @ChrisPollard the error looks like: User does not exist. (Service: AWSCognitoIdentityProvider; Status Code: 400; Error Code: UserNotFoundException; Request ID: 823e14a6-9d6e-11e8-867a-ab798cfb353a)

Comment: @JiewMeng I have a related question (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=875407) where I need the sub (UUID) in order to add a user to a group. Did you figure out how to do that?

Comment: @JiewMeng Were you able to resolve this?